# How to delete files from cloud storage after dataflow job completes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

In GCP, I have a dataflow job that does the job of copying files from cloud storage to big query.I would like to delete these files once they are successfully inserted  into big query. Can someone provide pointers on how to achieve this and also how to trigger another job after the previous one has succeeded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For these types of scenarios, its normally recommended that you introduce a tool for scheduling and workload orchestration into your architecture. Google Cloud provides [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/), a managed version of [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/), to solve exactly this use case. You can schedule a DAG (directed-acyclic graph) in Composer to start your Dataflow job and then, on the success of a job run, execute additional tasks for file cleanup or to kick off the next process.

### Example DAG

[image: Example DAG]

To get started I recommend checking out the Cloud Composer [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/) as well as these [Cloud Composer Examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/data-analytics/cloud-composer-examples) which seem similar to your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ryan McDowell. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Please update the Cloud Composer Examples link: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/examples/cloud-composer-examples